# Where to put the binary in CMake?

Tags: cmake

in my project, all source code resides in a folder named "src". There's a CMakeLists.txt file in my projects root (above "src"), but it merely declares the project and includes the "src" subdirectory. The CMakeLists.txt file under src does all the work, including "add_binary".

(Is that a common way of doing it, or should I put all the intelligence in the CMakeLists.txt file at the root level?)

If I build the project now, my binary is placed into the src folder, but this doesn't make a lot of sense, I'd rather have it in the root folder or a dedicated "bin" folder.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put all your executable files in a subdirectory called "bin", then you can use the following line in the top CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
```

Just remove `/bin` and executables will be created in the root directory. A similar variable exists for libraries: `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.

PS. Adding per-directory logic is fine. It seems to be the common way to do things and keeps things nicely organized.