# How to put test executables into a separate folder using CMake?

Tags: cmake

So I am doing an out of source build and would like my binaries to be in a `bin` folder. I use the following command for that

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

However, it would be great if all the executables that are actually just compiled tests (added via `add_test`) would end up in `bin/test`. What would be a good solution to achive this?

My project structure, where every test folder in unit_test_src has its own `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
root
|
---- src
|    ...
|
---- unit_test_src
|    ...
|
---- bin
|    |
|    ---- test
|
CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put the binary in CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431829/where-to-put-the-binary-in-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) is a global property. You can use [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) to set the directory for targets using [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html):

```
set_target_properties(
    test1 test2 ...
    PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/test
)
```